# Best way to pass store to a child of connected component in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What's the correct way to implement the below design?

```
<Parent with state>
   <connected element with Store configuration dependant on parent>
      <child of both, dependant on store/connected element>
   </connected element>
 </parent>
```

I'm not sure how much code to include and there's almost certainly more than I need so here's a snippet that I think explains what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
class SceneOne extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      opacity: 0,
      script: sceneOneScript
    };
  }

  render () {   
    return (
      <ScriptReader script = {this.state.script}> //This is connected and creates a store from the script passed via state.
        <Screen data-image="caves.png" data-opacity={this.state.opacity} >//This uses actual SceneOne.state.opacity which is updated to 1 after a delay in ComponentDidMount

          <ConditionalTitle  props = {this.props}/> //This needs the store.
         </Screen>
      </ScriptReader>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm really hoping that I don't need to connect `<ConditionalTitle>` because that feels like it breaks agnostic components principles.  I'm also hoping that I don't need to install `<ConditionalTitle>` inside the definition of `<ScriptReader>` because I'm planning on reusing it and passing different children/scripts etc.

ie. there'll be a  that has a `<ScreenReader>` child and it may not have a title, or may have elements that aren't required in `<SceneOne>`.

Comment: Have you thought about making a HOC for the ConditionalTitle and rendering it differently depending on the props you give it?

Comment: I think that's more or less what I'm trying to do, but I believe it should handle a limited set of responsibilities to keep the code clean.  I've currently got ConditionalDialog, ConditionalMenu as distinct logic packages.  these each have very different appearances, responsibilities etc.      As I think on it, I guess I could do a ScriptEvent component that owns the switching and calls in children. If I were to do that does it just become a child of ScriptReader or does it need  to have it's own Connect wrapper?

Comment: @BojanIvanac, can you write this up (use a HOC inside the definition of the ScriptReader that composes all of the options) as an answer.  I'll accept it as this has solved my issue.  Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a HOC inside the definition of the ScriptReader that composes all of the options